# What is "%!s" in the output of a float?

Tags: go

I'm getting coordinates (location) as an output of 2 float64 numbers, and it looks like this:

```
&{%!s(float64=42.539679) %!s(float64=42.601339)}
```

This is the first time I'm seeing anything like that, so what is "%!s"? 
"TypeOf" says "%!s(float64=42.539679)" is float64. So how do I work with this kind of floats? Is there any way to parse it, or somehow to make the %!s(float64=42.539679) look like 42.539679?

UPD: the highlighted line is a *tgbotapi.Location object from Syfaro's telegram bot api.
The api has this structure:

```
type Location struct {
    Longitude float64 `json:"longitude"`
    Latitude  float64 `json:"latitude"`
}
```

and the Location.Latitude gives me this: "%!s(float64=42.539679)" (float64)(?)

Comment: Where is that coordinates string coming from? How are you printing it out?

Comment: @ctcherry i updated the post.

Comment: If you want to read up on it head over to https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ and search for "Format errors"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

**%!s** is basically used in errors to help you identify a problem.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a matter of using an incorrect format "verb." You need to use `%f` instead of `%s`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var f float64 = 3.14
    fmt.Printf("attempting to print as string: %s \n", f)
    fmt.Printf("attempting to print as float: %f", f)
}
```

Runnable: https://play.golang.org/p/Pec_QrxBIl