# String format with errors with %e

Tags: go, error-handling

I've encountered some go code that appears to use `%e` for formatting an error for display to the screen.  A simplified version would be code like this

```
err := errors.New("La de da")
fmt.Printf("%e\n", err)
```

outputs

```
&{%!e(string=La de da)}
```

However, if I look at the [go manual](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), it says `%e` is for formatting floating point numbers in scientific notation.  That output doesn't look like scientific notation, so I'm wondering

1. If this is a specific notation, what is it? (i.e. is there a `%.` formatting option I could use to get that format)
2. If it's not a specific notation, what weird thing is going on under the hood that leads to an error being rendered in this way?
3. What silly, obvious thing am I missing that renders most of what I've said in this post wrong?

Comment: Your error value isn't a floating point or complex number which is what `%e` formats, it's an error.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242201/golang-what-is-s

Comment: Thank you for feedback @jimB -- I realize the error isn't a floating point number -- but I'd expect a string formater to either 1. Complain about the type mismatch, 2. Try to cast the variable as the other type.  There's some third thing happening here that I don't follow.  I'd like to understand what format is, and why golang chose it.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning scroll up a bit to " Format errors: " The most relevant to your example being `Wrong type or unknown verb: %!verb(type=value)`.

Comment: The fmt package uses the `%!` output to indicate a format errors.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva -- that's what I was missing. I'm happy to upvote/accept that as a formal answer if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned you're free to close/delete the question @AlanStorm. I'm glad I could be of help though.

Comment: Error types can implement fmt.Formatter such that the %e format actually produces useful output. That would be unusual though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the Go documentation.

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> Printing
>
> Format errors:
>
> If an invalid argument is given for a verb, such as providing a string
>   to %d, the generated string will contain a description of the problem,
>   as in these examples:
>
> ```
> Wrong type or unknown verb: %!verb(type=value)
>   Printf("%d", hi):          %!d(string=hi)
> Too many arguments: %!(EXTRA type=value)
>   Printf("hi", "guys"):      hi%!(EXTRA string=guys)
> Too few arguments: %!verb(MISSING)
>   Printf("hi%d"):            hi%!d(MISSING)
> Non-int for width or precision: %!(BADWIDTH) or %!(BADPREC)
>   Printf("%*s", 4.5, "hi"):  %!(BADWIDTH)hi
>   Printf("%.*s", 4.5, "hi"): %!(BADPREC)hi
> Invalid or invalid use of argument index: %!(BADINDEX)
>   Printf("%*[2]d", 7):       %!d(BADINDEX)
>   Printf("%.[2]d", 7):       %!d(BADINDEX)
> ```
>
> All errors begin with the string "%!" followed sometimes by a single
>   character (the verb) and end with a parenthesized description.

---

For your example,

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    err := errors.New("La de da")
    fmt.Printf("%e\n", err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NKC6WWePyxM

Output:

```
&{%!e(string=La de da)}
```

Documentation:

> All errors begin with the string "%!" followed sometimes by a single
>   character (the verb) and end with a parenthesized description.
>
> ```
> Wrong type or unknown verb: %!verb(type=value)
>   Printf("%d", hi):          %!d(string=hi)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

When formatting errors into strings using fmt.Printf()/Println(), you can do the following:

```golang
err := fnThatReturnsErr()
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("The error is %v", err)
}
```

I believe %v is the formatting option you were looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not correct. `%w` only works in the special case of `fmt.Errorf("more details %w", err)`. And what it produces isn't (only) a string with the error's message in it, but a "wrapped error", that is an error which extends an already existing error. This allows adding more information while still using `errors.Is(...)` to check for underlying errors